# Pass data to EJS include

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to implement a recursive include in EJS.  I am using ExpressJS 4.  I need to be able to selectively pass in data to the include.  My "sub" variable changes with loop iteration and therefore cannot work globally.
However I am getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" which means that the if statement in the partial is always evaluating to true.

This is my main HTML:

```
<ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
<% agents.forEach (function(sub) { var subs = sub.agents; %>
<li>
    <a href="#"><%= sub.fname +' ' +sub.lname %></a>
    <% if (subs) { %>
    <% include dropdown.html %>
    <% } %>
</li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

This is my include (dropdown.html):

```
<ul class="f-dropdown">

    <% subs.forEach(function(sub) { %>
    <li>
    <a href="#"><%= sub.fname +' ' +sub.lname %></a>
    <% if (sub.agents && sub.agents.length) {subs = sub.agents; %>
    <% include dropdown.html %>
    <% } %>
    </li>
    <% }); %>

</ul>
```

UPDATE:
Even this doesn't work:

```
<ul class="f-dropdown">
    <% if (sub.agents && sub.agents.length > 0) { %>
        <% (function(subs) { %>
            <% include dropdown.html %>
        <% })(sub.agents); %>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

I'm about to try [JUST](https://github.com/baryshev/just)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622011/node-ejs-passing-data-to-an-include

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the visionmedia ejs library doesn't support passing parameters into includes. However it handles plain javascript pretty well, so you could try an IIFE closure to handle the scope changes:

```
<a href="#"><%= sub.fname +' ' +sub.lname %></a>
<% if (sub.agents && sub.agents.length) { %>
    <% (function() { %>
        <% var subs = sub.agents; %>
        <% include dropdown.html %>
    <% })(); %>
<% } %>
```

Let me know if that works for you; I'm happy to investigate further if it doesn't.

Comment: That's a brilliant answer!  Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  I still get "Maximum call stack size exceeded".  Most likely the subs var is the same and always passing the test.
But I feel encouraged that we're close.

Comment: I've tried everything.  It just isn't changing the 'sub' var per iteration as expected.