# Node EJS passing data to an include

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

Currently I'm messing around with Node and EJS templates.

However I have hit a problem. Im building up a page made up of multiple components and im calling these components into the index page like so:

```
<% include components/header.ejs %>
```

My question is how can I pass data (json) to that specific include?

I want to be able to reuse components however to show different content coming from json.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<%- include('components/header.ejs', {data: 'data'}); %>
```

Comment: I tried this and i get an error Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Comment: "Includes" are relative to the template with the `include` call. If you have this statement`<%- include('components/header.ejs', {data: 'data'}); %>` in a file  `/templates/main.ejs`,  there should be `/templates/components/header.ejs`.

Comment: it errors still when i use the filename .ejs but in the path is shows as the following: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory /views/('components/header.ejs', {data: 'data'})

Comment: Looks like the path is incorrect. Update please your post with your file structure and the statement you are calling.

Comment: Thanks path  was incorrect. I also forgot to add <%- when calling the json in the template